# Boxfuse SSL Config with GoDaddy Certs

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, cloudcaptain

I have an Spring Boot App deployed at AWS with Boxfuse . I am trying to make the SSL work with "mydomain.com" .I got the certs from Godaddy . It works well with self-signed certificates. But when I tried it with GoDaddy certs , it says that Payload failed to come up within 300s . Do I need to configure anything at AWS or Godaddy .Right now I am having following configuration in my `application.properties` file .

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:example.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=myS3cr3tPwd
server.ssl.trust-store=/cacerts/example.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=my0th3rPwd
```

Logs says this :

```
2017-01-19 09:22:38.315  INFO 895 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbedded
ServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 443 (https)
2017-01-19 09:22:38.338  INFO 895 --- [           main] com.unoiatech.o3.Applica
tion             : Started Application in 50.814 seconds (JVM running for 51.171
)
The system is going down NOW!
Sent SIGTERM to all processes
2017-01-19 09:26:34.501  INFO 895 --- [       Thread-4] ationConfigEmbeddedWebAp
plicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationC
onfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@73f0f3d4: startup date [Thu Jan 19 09:21:48 G
MT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-19 09:26:34.530  INFO 895 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBea
nExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-01-19 09:26:34.553  INFO 895 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityMa
nagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'defaul
t'
Sent SIGKILL to all processes
Requesting system poweroff
[  290.976653] reboot: Power down
```

I have no clue where to look for the issue . Any help would be appreciated .

**Edit :**

It is a t2.micro instance . [image: Boxfuse App]

Command to run the app : `boxfuse run myapp:1.x -env=test` ,

**Edit After adding port to command** :

[image: error image]

Also, It is working with  port 8443.

Comment: Make sure your application returns an HTTP 200 at / by accessing its IP directly during the time Boxfuse performs its healthcheck.

Comment: @AxelFontaine application returns 200 with https and not with http .

Comment: And it says  : Waiting for payload to start at http : //xx.xxx.xx.xx:443/

Comment: Please also include your Boxfuse configuration and the parameters you passed to the Boxfuse command

Comment: @AxelFontaine Please check I have added them .

Comment: What intrigues me is the fact that the port 443 is somehow discovered as an http port instead of https. What happens when you add `-ports.https=443` when fusing the image?

Comment: I did not tried that . I will try that and let you know shortly . Also, in case of self-signed certs I was using 8443 .

Comment: @AxelFontaine I tried with -ports.https=443 . It is giving error . Please check the question for the details .

Comment: This is most likely due to your certificate having been improperly imported into your KeyStore. If you fix that things should work.

Comment: @AxelFontaine but certificate is working with port 8443 .

Comment: application is running at https ://www.mydomain:8443/

Comment: @AxelFontaine Thanks for helping me out with this .It works with  -ports.https=443 .

Answer (score 0):

- Use PKCS12 format
- I faced same issue solved using below command

  > openssl pkcs12 -export -in f8f628911xyzc.crt -inkey mydomain.com.key
  >   -certfile gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -out mydomain.p12